# TypeError: Cannot read property 'timeFormat' of undefined

Tags: javascript, class, d3.js, polymer, javascript-objects

I am creating a chart using d3 js and I was trying to convert a `DateTime` string to `time`. but it is returning `TypeError: Cannot read property 'timeFormat' of undefined`

The bellow is the full file that Created.

````
import {BaseElement} from '../../core/base-element';
import {utilsMixin} from '../../core/mixins/utils-mixin';

// import {LitElement} from 'lit-element';
import * as d3 from 'd3';



export const AreaChartBase = class extends utilsMixin(dataSourceMixin(BaseElement)) {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.title = '';
        this.chartTheme = {
            margin : {
                top: 35, 
                right: 145, 
                bottom: 35, 
                left: 45
            },
            barsColors : '#23d160',
            tickColor : '#aeaeae',
            pathColor : '#aeaeae',
            gridColor : '#aeaeae', 
            barTitleColor : "#23d160",
        }
    }


    static get is() {
        return 'area-chart';
    }

    static get properties() {

        return {
            title: String,
            chartTheme: Object,
        }
    }

    timeFormat(str){
        const dateTimeString = new Date(str);
        const time = dateTimeString.getTime();
        
        const normalTime = new Date(time).toLocaleDateString("en-US");

        return normalTime;
    }
    
    areaChart(selector, props, data){
        // initialize the variables
        const {
            margin, 
            width, 
            height, 
            barsColors, 
            tickColor, 
            pathColor, 
            gridColor, 
            barTitleColor
        } = props;
        
        const innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right;
        const innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        const svg = d3.select(selector);

        let chart = svg.selectAll('svg')
            .data([null]);

        chart = chart.enter()
            .append('svg')
            .merge(svg)
                // .attr('width', innerWidth)
                // .attr('height', innerHeight);
                .attr('viewBox', `0,0, ${innerWidth}, ${innerHeight}`)

        chart.append('text')
            .attr('x', 0)             
            .attr('y', margin.top / 2)
            .attr('text-anchor', 'start')  
            .style('font-size', '18px') 
            .attr('fill', '#4c6072') 
            .text('Area chart');


        let g = chart.selectAll('g').data([null]);

        g = g.enter()
            .append('g')
            .merge(g)
                .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);


        // Add X axis --> it is a date format
        const x = d3.scaleBand()
            .rangeRound([0, innerWidth])
            .padding(0.1);
        
        const y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .range([innerHeight - margin.bottom - 17, 0]);
        
        x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
            console.log(this.timeFormat(d[0]));
            return this.timeFormat(d[0]);
        }));

        y.domain( d3.extent(data, function(d) { return +d[4]; }) );

        const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

        const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
            .ticks(5)
            .tickSizeInner(-innerWidth)
            .tickSizeOuter(0)
            .tickPadding(10);

        let xAxisG = g.selectAll('.x axis').data([null]);

        xAxisG = xAxisG.enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'x axis')
            .merge(xAxisG)
                .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${innerHeight - margin.bottom - 17})`)
        
        let yAxisG = g.selectAll('y axis').data([null]);
        yAxisG = yAxisG.enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'y axis')
            .merge(yAxisG)

        xAxisG.call(xAxis);
        xAxisG.selectAll('.tick text')
            .attr('fill', tickColor)
        xAxisG.selectAll('.tick line')
            .attr('stroke', pathColor);
        xAxisG.select('.domain')
            .attr('stroke', 'transparent');

        yAxisG.call(yAxis);
        yAxisG.selectAll('.tick text')
            .attr('fill', tickColor)
        yAxisG.selectAll('.tick line')
            .attr('stroke', pathColor);
        yAxisG.select('.domain')
            .attr('stroke', 'transparent');  

        // append the svg object to the body of the page
        // let svg = d3.select(selector)
        //     .append("svg")
        //     .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        //     .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        //     .append("g")
        //     .attr("transform",
        //     "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        
        // const x = d3.scaleBand()
        //     .domain(data.map(function (d) {
        //         return d[0];
        //     }))
        //     .range([ 0, width ]);

        // svg.append("g")
        //     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height+5) + ")")
        //     .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5).tickSizeOuter(0));

        // // Add Y axis
        // var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        //     .domain( d3.extent(data, function(d) { return +d[4]; }) )
        //     .range([ height, 0 ]);

        // svg.append("g")
        //     .attr("transform", "translate(-5,0)")
        //     .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSizeOuter(0));

        // Add the area
        svg.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")
            .attr("fill-opacity", .3)
            .attr("stroke", "none")
            .attr("d", d3.area()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d[0]) })
            .y0( height )
            .y1(function(d) { return y(+d[4]) })
            )

        // Add the line
        svg.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "#69b3a2")
            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
            .attr("d", d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d[0]) })
            .y(function(d) { return y(+d[4]) })
            )

        // Add the line
        svg.selectAll("myCircles")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("fill", "red")
            .attr("stroke", "none")
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d[0]) })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(parseInt(d[4])) })
            .attr("r", 2)
        
    }

    initAreaChart(dsc){
        const rows = dsc.rows;
        const data = dsc.data;
        const cont = this.qs('#chart');

        this.areaChart(cont, Object.assign({}, this.chartTheme, {
            width: this.qs('#container').clientWidth,
            height: 400,
        }), rows);
    }

    firstUpdated(changedProperties) {
        super.firstUpdated(changedProperties);
        let self = this;

        this.loader.then(dsc => {
            self.initAreaChart(dsc);
        });
    }

    dscDataName() {
        return this.e.defaultValue;
    }

    init(pElement, loader) {
        super.init(pElement, loader);
        var self = this;
        self.loader = this.loadData();
    }

}```

if you guys can help me find a fix for the above error I will appreciate it. Thanks in advance
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use arrow function. Arrow functions keep context.

```
 x.domain(data.map( (d) => {
       console.log(this.timeFormat(d[0]));
       return this.timeFormat(d[0]);
   }));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this